# Days difference between two dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I've been trying many ways to calculate the round number of days between two dates, I mean, counting the whole days. An example of what I need:

```
   START DATE            END DATE          Day Count  

24/02/2010 16:26     24/02/2010 16:26         1  
20/02/2010 18:16     24/02/2010 16:26         5  
31/12/2009 20:00     24/02/2010 16:26         56  
15/07/2009 20:59     24/02/2010 16:26         225
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

DateTime's can be subtracted to get a TimeSpan. The TimeSpan has a TotalDays which is the number of days (includes fractional days as well).

```
int DaysBetween(DateTime d1, DateTime d2) {
    TimeSpan span = d2.Subtract(d1);
    return (int)span.TotalDays;
}
```

**NOTE** Time spans are signed. If d1=1/9/11 and d2=1/11/11, then d1.subtract(d2)=timespan of -2 days. So if you want to use a time span to find out if dates are within X days of each other, you need to take the absolute value of the total days...

```
Math.Abs(span.TotalDays)
```

Comment: My solution in VB.NET:

        Dim ts As TimeSpan
        ts = s.Subtract(DateTime.Parse(h))
        Dim days As Integer
        days = ts.TotalDays + 1

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [subtraction operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_subtraction.aspx) on the two instances of [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) (or [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx), as it has the same [subtraction operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.op_subtraction.aspx), and it is the [recommended structure to use for date values in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267.aspx)) to get a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) instance.

Once you have that, you can call the [`Days` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx) to get the number of whole days that the `TimeSpan` represents.

If you want the number of whole and fractional days, then look at the [`TotalDays` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx).

In your specific case, it seems that you want to add 1 to whatever value the `Days` property returns, as your custom calculation indicates that for two `DateTime` instances that represent the same value, the result is 1.

Answer (score 13):

```
DateTime dtOne;
DateTime dtTwo;

// to get the total days in between
int answer = (dtTwo - dtOne).TotalDays
```

Comment: `TimeSpan.TotalDays` returns a double, so you'll need a conversion to `int` in there.

Comment: Actually, you could just use TimeSpan.Days if you'd like int as return type