# how many days between two selected dates

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Days difference between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330302/days-difference-between-two-dates)

I need to know how many days between two selected dates.
typically for comparing dates I use DateTime.CompareTo, but here the situation is different.
thanks in advance and sorry for stupid question.

Comment: This question was asked way too many times (including special case for business days - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates) and seraching for it should have provided an answer.

Comment: `Math.Abs(d1.Subtract(d2).Days)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
   int DaysBetween(DateTime d1, DateTime d2) {
    TimeSpan span = d2.Subtract(d1);
    return Math.Abs((int)span.TotalDays);
}
```

///

```
Console.WriteLine(DaysBetween(DateTime.Now.AddDays(10), DateTime.Now) );
```

will return 10

Comment: `(int)span.TotalDays = span.Days` right? why dont you just return that?

Answer (score 1):

Not an original solution but:

```
DateTime d1=DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime d2=DateTime.MaxValue;
TimeSpan span=d2-d1;
Console.WriteLine
         ( "There're {0} days between {1} and {2}" , span.TotalDays, d1.ToString(), d2.ToString() );
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/0625cefa-461b-4a3c-b7f0-d39d06741b70/

Answer (score 1):

try this (you can improve it using .net TimeSpan class)

```
        public static int DateDiff(string Interval, DateTime Date1, DateTime Date2)
    {
        int difVale = 0;
        DateTime startDate, endDate;

        if (Date1 > Date2)
        {
            endDate = Date1; 
            startDate = Date2;
        }
        else
        {
            startDate = Date1; 
            endDate = Date2;
        }
        switch (Interval)
        {
            case "D":
            case "d":
                for (int nYear = startDate.Year; nYear < endDate.Year; nYear++)
                {
                    difVale += new DateTime(nYear, 12, 31).DayOfYear;
                }
                difVale += endDate.DayOfYear - startDate.DayOfYear;
                break;

            case "M":
            case "m":
                difVale = endDate.Year - startDate.Year;
                difVale = difVale * 12;
                difVale += endDate.Month - startDate.Month;
                break;
            case "Y":
            case "y":
                difVale = endDate.Year - startDate.Year;
                break;
        }
        if (Date1 > Date2)
        {
            difVale = -difVale;
        }
        return difVale;
    }
```