# Conversion of variables

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datetimepicker

Hi guys i have a problem with this code that i found...
i have 2 datetimepickers and i would like to find the difference in days between both of the 2 datetimepickers.

```
 textBox1.Text = ((dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value)).TotalDays.ToString("#");
```

I cannot convert the textbox to a string nor a int...I do not understand what does the ToString("#") means too.........
The results from the codes are wierd too...
[Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNf0M.png)

[Result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WKpf.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330302/days-difference-between-two-dates

Comment: I don't know what ToString("#") means either.  Why is it in there?  What's wrong with just ToString()?

Comment: ToString("#") converts to something but i am not sure what it means.... Definitely not the same as ToString();

Comment: I'm not familiar with the # parameter but regardless why are you using it and what happens when you don't?

Comment: The `#` character is a [custom numeric format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings), which specifies the number of digits to display. Non-significant zeros are not displayed, which is why you see nothing when the number of days difference is zero.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having, though? The output you show looks correct to me (aside from the fact that there is no `0` displayed for the first picture, but that's easily fixed by removing the `#` altogether or replacing it with `0`).

Comment: Just wanted to know what is the # means... can you guys stop downvoting its hurting my feelings:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the difference in days between  2 datetimepickers values, you can try this code also,

```
TimeSpan tSpan = dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value;
textBox1.Text = tSpan.TotalDays.ToString("#");
```

`#` in the string format represents the number of significant digits to display.
When it is after the decimal place, the resulting number will be rounded to the number of digits.
For example:

```
 5.67.ToString("#");
```

your result will be: `6`

In the case of

```
5.67.ToString("#.#")
```

your result will be: `5.7`

and in the case of

```
5.67.ToString("#.##")
```

your result will be: `5.67`

Comment: `tSpan.TotalDays` not `tSpan.Days`

Comment: Thanks @CodingYoshi you are right. Days is a simple int value, where as TotalDays is a double so it can express fractional days too.

Comment: What do you mean by *"optional"*? That is not entirely correct...Look at the difference between `5.67.ToString("#")` and `5.67.ToString("#.#")` and `5.67.ToString("#.##")`. It represents the number of significant digits to display, and when it's after the decimal place, the resulting number will be rounded to that number of digits.

Comment: Thats not the only difference.  There are major difference please see MSDN

Comment: I Misunderstood. Thank you for the information @RufusL

Comment: Thanks for the explaination

Comment: @NoobCoder see the updated answer. I have updated the answer based on the information I got from Rufus L and  CodingYoshi.Thanks  to them.